# pythonのクロスコンパイルについて

Tags: python, python3, windows, macos, ubuntu

現在ubuntu環境をメインにpythonでのツール開発をしているのですが、主要OS向けビルドの為と処理速度やドライバの多さなどからmacに移りたいと思っています。

macでwindows向けビルド(exe化など、pyinstallerではホストOSに依存することは理解しています)、逆にwindowsからubuntu向けなどができないか模索しているのですが、できる方法はないでしょうか。

単純にソース渡してビルドできればいいので、何かしらいい方法はないでしょうか。
コンテナなどで解決など方法があればご教授いただけると幸いです。
なお、ターゲットはx64,windows11向けです。

Comment: 質問者さんご自身は把握されているのでしょうが、何をビルドして何を得るか肝心なところが書かれていません。「python開発」とはありますが文字通り解釈するならpython本体の開発と読めますが、きっとそのような意図の質問ではないと想像しますので、質問対象を明示してください。パッケージという語が登場していないので、 .py から .pyc を作る話かしら？

Comment: すみません、pythonを用いたツールの開発です。pyからpyc、もっと言うならexeのような実行ファイルを生成できればと思っています。最も、pyinstallerのようなライブラリーも全て包括した実行ファイル生成ができればと思っております。

Comment: こんなリポジトリとか記事があって、使われている各々の版数は古いようですが、同様のものがあるか探してみるとか、それを参考に自分で最新版を作るとかしてみては？ [cdrx/docker-pyinstaller](https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller), [PyInstaller Windows](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pyinstaller-windows), [minidocks/pyinstaller](https://hub.docker.com/r/minidocks/pyinstaller), [Docker環境のPyInstallerでキレイにExe化する](https://qiita.com/ryoheiszk/items/2ea26594d24304c721e2), [PythonのWindows用EXE化をDockerコンテナで実現する方法](https://qiita.com/torun225/items/9756983b6907b5a7c54e), [Create Pyinstaller app on Docker running Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73927602/9014308)

Comment: ターゲットマシン x64,windows11 に Pythonをインストール出来ないのでしょうか？(何か理由あるなら示せる範囲で構わないので …)

Comment: 「exeのような」とあえて濁していますが、これだと `.bat`+`.py`でも構わないような気がします。明確に`.exe`にターゲットが絞られていないのでしょうか？ コメント補足するのではなく、質問文をより正確にしてください。 / でもそこまでWindowsにターゲットを絞っているなら、無理にLinuxやMacを使わず素直にWindowsを使えばいいのでは… どのみち成果物はWindows上で動作確認するんですよね？

Comment: PyInstaller に言及されているので、恐らくここでのビルド(やコンパイル)は「Python のインストールされていない環境でも実行できるよう、単一ファイルにパッケージする」事を指していると仮定すると、PyInstaller はクロスコンパイラではないので、実行環境に合わせた実機を用意するか、コンテナ等の技術を使う形になりそうです。 / スクリプトの状態ならポータブル(移植性)を保っているはずなので、なぜ敢えてコンパイルが必要なのかを今一度検討した方がよさそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます
pyinstallerに言及理由する理由はクライアント側でpythonインストール作業を伴ってしまうためです。
それを抜きにして単純に実行ファイルだけ動作するようにしたいという形で
その際にコンパイルするマシンOSに実行ファイルが依存すると、各OS向けにマシンを用意しなくてはならないのかと悩んでいます。(仮想環境はメモリーを消費するので避けたい)
1.まとめると相手のマシンにpythonインストール作業をさせないで実行させたい
2.クロスコンパイルでホストOSがなんであれターゲットのOS向けに書き出せれば良い
という感じです